# reloadData no funciona Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

Tengo un problema al querer hacer un filtro dentro de un TableView los datos se obtienen desde un servicio web al momento de cargarlos por primera vez todo funciona bien, pero al escribir una letra en el searchBar la tabla se vacía aunque tenga coincidencias en los datos ya obtenidos.
Tengo poco en Swift y no se cual pudiera ser la solución desde ya gracias.

```
        //Funcion que se ejecuta cuando el texto cambia en el searchBar
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == ""{
            isSearching = false
            view.endEditing(true)
            tabla.reloadData()
        }else{
            isSearching = true
            usuarioBuscar = usuariosArray.filter { ($0.cliente?.contains(searchText) ?? isSearching)}
            tabla.reloadData()
        }//else
        }//searchBar
```

Comment: duda, tienes un arreglo para tu filtrado a parte de el que usas para tu lista? si utilizas el mismo arreglo donde estas obteniendo la info, ahi esta el problema, si usas ese mismo arreglo para llenar tu tabla, al inicio todo ok, pero buscas no encuentra nada ese arreglo queda vacío.. y pues tendrías que volver a obtener desde los servicios tu data, en caso de no obtener... pero estarías haciendo retrabajo estar llenando el mismo arreglo siempre, no es lo correcto si fuera el caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo esta función en un proyecto. Lo que hace es buscar el texto y compararlo independientemente de mayúsculas o minúsculas y lo agrega al array para mostrar en la tabla.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        self.usuarioBuscar = usuariosArray.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
            let tmp: NSString = text.cliente! as NSString
            let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
            return range.location != NSNotFound
        })

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Que tal buen dia he probado tu código y no me genera errores pero al ejecutarlo tengo el mismo problema al poner cualquier letra en el buscador la tabla no da ningún resultado, no se si sea la manera en que obtengo los datos, de cualquier forma gracias

Comment: Puedes agregar la función cellForRowAt, puedes hacer un print de la variable **self.usuarioBuscar** para ver qué valores se almacenan

Comment: que tal he estado probando con imprimir los valores de self.usuarioBuscar  en diferentes lugares y me di cuenta de algo
 `func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        print(usuarioBuscar)
        usuarioBuscar = usuariosArray.filter{$0.cliente == searchText}
        isSearching = true
        tabla.reloadData()
    }//searchBar`
ahí si me imprime los datos correctamente
`        usuarioBuscar = usuariosArray.filter{$0.cliente == searchText}
        print(usuarioBuscar)`
y si lo dejo así solo me imprime un arreglo vacío

Comment: Entonces en donde muestras los valores filtrados en las celdas debe estar fallando.

Comment: Ya logre hacer que funcionara y si era un error mío al asignar los valores de los arreglos, de echo probé tu código y funciona perfecto. Gracias.